# Select cannot be pressed in android phone, but can be selected in iphone

Tags: android, html

https://www.mooimom.id/product/3-pack-items/

the "< select >" suddenly does not work on android phones but it worked on iphones? It worked on desktop browsers (i tried on chrome) and mobile mimic (reducing the size of the browser in chrome).

I tried fastclick, does not change anything, did Google change something? their native UI for when you selected "< select >" does not work suddenly. It worked on iphones. I swear i did not change anything, it suddenly does not work since Saturday. Kinda stuck, please help.

Basically the main problem is that now in android browsers, when i press the select, it does not show the native-UI for < select >

Here's the weird thing, the < select > worked in android phones if i request "desktop mode / version"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, after connecting my android to my laptop and debug the Chrome with Remote debugging, i found the problem, basically it's because of breaking change in android's browsers.

https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5093566007214080

```
Treat Document Level Touch Event Listeners as Passive

AddEventListenerOptions defaults passive to false. With this change touchstart and touchmove listeners added to the document will default to passive:true (so that calls to preventDefault will be ignored)..

If the value is explicitly provided in the AddEventListenerOptions it will continue having the value specified by the page.

This is behind a flag starting in Chrome 54, and enabled by default in Chrome 56. See https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/01/scrolling-intervention
```